# Could Wordpress be used/extended as a medium-size ecommerce site?

Tags: e-commerce

Is wordpress reliable enough and could it be used with a proper plugin as a medium sized ecommerce site? We are talking around 1500 products here, estimates say around 5 to 10 costumers per day, usually returning ones. Some days none.

I have a client who wants to sell online. We are situated in a country where people dont see web as something serious enough. Still, they literally have a budget of pretty much **none**. And 1500 products to sell online.

Magento, or any other open source ecommerce platform are out of the question, there is just no resources for starting something like that. Or any time.  Only way is something **free**, **small**, absolutely **not resource hungry** as Wordpress.

I have to fight with making it work with only what i have at disposal.  Also, if you can recommend any wordpress plugin for the job(WP-ecommerce?), i will be very thankful.  I guess something paid, up to maximum 50$ would work too.

Answer (score 2):

WordPress can make an excellent e-commerce platform  ...

There are some very good ecommerce solutions for WordPress including

- [WooCommerce](http://www.woothemes.com/woocommerce/) - free and has premium extentions like [table rate
  shipping](http://www.woothemes.com/extension/table-rate-shipping/) and themes - Sth African parent company with 30++
  ecommerce extensions and 90+ WP themes
- [Jigoshop](http://jigoshop.com/) - free and WooCommerce was forked
  from this - UK based company
- WordPress ecommerce by [Get Shopped](http://getshopped.org/)
  is one of the best known and oldest options around. It has a free and premium
  versions - NZ based company
- WPMU - Aus based company has an annual premium membership fee which meets most of your needs

Personally I think choice comes down to other factors

1. Payment gateways (who they want to use for payment and is there an extension for them.
2. Payment options & subscriptions (one off, monthly recurring)
3. How technical / skilled is your customer for setting up and managing an e-commerce shop.
4. What other marketing / sales promotions will they want (like cross linking / upselling content)
5. Do you need to manage variations of the same product (by colour or size / weight / length)
6. Delivery options / couriers - eg Royal Mail here in the UK, has a plugin for WooCommerce

to be honest ... I can say it is likely that GetShopped or WooCommerce can do all of these so it will be a matter of adding up the premium / plugins costs.

There are plenty of other WordPress ecommerce solutions, but many of them will not meet all 5 of these requirements

This is taken from another answer of mine: [Shopping Cart Solution](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57766/shopping-cart-solution/57767#57767)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I agree with Damiens response,

Second - I have recently rolled out two eCom sites, 1 using GetShopped and the other with WPStore Cart.

both have pluses and minus' the difference for me came down to the supported payment gateways and the client requirements. 1 client was in Montana and wanted a shop that hooked into Quickbooks and US postal services, other client was Aust based and we used eWay.

In my experience, I have spent less time supporting the GetShopped site and my developer was able to customise it to better cater for product variations. My sites both had a similar number of products, and due to the way Store Cart manages its products, I couldn't imaging doing a larger site using it, where GetShopped is a bit more neater to work with.

Downside, there is some issues with hooking into PayPal (may be our integration though) as the Gateway with transactions that have been completed, are not marked as such in the backend. So the client has a number of open transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are a number of free plugins that extend wordpress for use as an eCommerce platform.

Here is a [review of 5 of them](http://www.wordpress-ecommerce.com/5-free-ecommerce-plugins-for-wordpress-373)

See also the `ecommerce` tag in the wordpress plugin directory: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/ecommerce

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the [Jigoshop](http://jigoshop.com/) plugin, I've used it a few times and it hasn't failed to meet my requirements yet. I also seems to be growing rapidly and there's almost daily bolt on's.

It's free and the standard version meets most requirements but should you want anything extra then the bolt on's are extremely cheap - ranging from $10-50.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress by defaultly provide functionality of blogging. You can use wordpress as e-commerce solutions. For this you can use different
e-commerce plugins available in market.

Below are the some e-commerce plugins

1. WooCommerce
2. Easy Digital Downloads
3. WP eCommerce
4. MarketPress